# Android Rapid Scroll Implementation

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android

For those who use WhatsApp, when you want to scroll to the top, there is a sort of rectangular "handle" feature on the side of the ScrollView that lets you touch on it, hold and slide and linearly Scrolls to the top of the ScrollView.

It is sort of like the alphabets on the side in your Contacts or Music list, except there is this rectangular handle.

[image]

I have been Googling for a bunch of keywords related to ScrollView, Touch gesture, long press, but I could find out what this feature is. It's definitely not a Scroller.

Does anybody have any idea what this feature is? Is it an Android Class or a third party Scolling library?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature in listview.  If you add 
     setFastSrollEnabled(true)

And if you scroll,  the bar is shown. You can try it with scroll view

Comment: You can also use `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"` in the xml layout.

Comment: Yes thats true +1 from me

Comment: So I guess I'll have to embed ListView within my ScrollView. Thanks all!